# Mocking is sometimes not applied when running a multi-class testsuite

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, junit, mockito, project-reactor

I am testing a service which heavily relies on project reactor.

For many tests I am mocking the return value of the component responsible for API calls.
The tests are split over multiple files.
When I run the tests of one file, they are green, but when I execute all of the test files at once, some tests fail, with the error message indicating that the mocking did not succeed (Either the injected component returned `null`, or the implementation of the actual component is invoked).
In the logs, there is no information about the mocking failing.

A code example:

```
interface API {
  Flux<Bird> getBirds();
}

@Component
class BirdWatcher {
  API api;
  BirdWatcher(API api) {
    this.api = api;
  }
  
  Flux<Bird> getUncommonBirds() {
    return api.getBirds()           // Although this is mocked in the test, in some runs it returns `null` or calls the implementation of the actual component
      .filter(Bird::isUncommon);
  }
}

@SpringBootTest
class BirdWatcherTests {
  @Autowired
  BirdWatcher birdWatcher;
  @MockBean
  API api;
  
  @Test
  void findsUncommonBirds() {
    // Assemble
    Bird birdCommon = new Bird("Sparrow", "common");
    Bird birdUncommon = new Bird("Parrot", "uncommon");
    Mockito.when(api.getBirds()).thenReturn(Flux.just(birdCommon, birdUncommon));
    
    // Act
    Flux<Bird> uncommonBirds = birdWatcher.getUncommonBirds();
    
    // Assert
    assertThat(uncommonBirds.collectList().block().size(), equalTo(1));
  }
}
```

For me the issue seems like a race condition, but I don't know where and how this might happen, and how I can check and fix this.

I am using `spring-boot-test:2.7.8`, pulling in `org.mockito:mockito-core:4.5.1` `org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:4.5.1`, and `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.2`, with gradle 7.8.
For reactor, `spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.7.8`, depending on `reactor:2.7.8`.

Comment: You write: "when I execute multiple test files at once, it fails" – and then you only show a single test? Don't you think the chances of getting a good answer are higher if you provide a [mre] that actually exhibits the problem? Because, if I understood correctly, with a single file/test, all works just fine (so you are only showing code that already works)

Comment: Does "at once" mean serially, or in parallel?

Comment: Sorry for not following up!

> Does "at once" mean serially, or in parallel? 
Serial

 I fixed this by annotating each class with `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what the problem was, but I fixed this by annotating each class with `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)`